# Error while installing object detection API: ImportError: cannot import name 'Cycler'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Okay so this has been making me crazy, I am trying to set up the tensorflow object detection api, I have followed all the steps mentioned on the github page. However, on the last step when we need to check the installation by running:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

This error shows up:

[image: ImportError: cannot import name 'Cycler']

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/mnt/data2/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 34, in <module>
    from object_detection.meta_architectures import ssd_meta_arch
  File "/mnt/data2/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 34, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils
  File "/mnt/data2/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
  File "/localdisk/workspace/pycharm/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/localdisk/workspace/pycharm/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from cycler import Cycler, cycler as ccycler
ImportError: cannot import name 'Cycler'
```

cycler is already installed but somehow its not able to import it. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in the separate virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. I was in a separate environment and that was the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is fixed. I was using Anaconda and had created a separate virtual environment. The problem was that I had to extend my python path. I just exported the path of the site-packages and put it in to the bashrc and it all got fixed.

Comment: Can you pleas be more specific? Add code snippets etc...